# maximum sum according to given criteria

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was solving one question given me as an assignment. I tried hard but unable to reach optimal solution.

> There are N shops, all aligned linearly having index 1,2,3...N. Buying any
>    positive number of items from a shop `S(i)` gives a happiness equal to `H(i)` . 
>    Unfortunately due to some unavoidable circumstances, every shop owner has 
>    introduced a value `L(i)`. You are credited `H(i)` happiness from the `i`th shop if
>   and only if this is the first shop you are buying something from or you buy
>   at least one item from this shop and the last shop you shopped from was `S(j)`
>   such that `L(j)≤L(i)` and `j<i`. Find the maximum sum of happiness that can be 
>   obtained following the rules given above!

I thought to apply max subarray sum along with keeping `L(i)` as criteria.  here is the code->>

```
long long ans=INT_MIN, temp=0, prev=-1;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    l = L[i];
    if(l>=prev){
        temp+=H[i];
        if(temp<0){
            temp = 0;
            prev = -1;
        }
        if(temp>ans){
            ans = temp;
            prev=L[i];
        }
    }
    else{
        if(H[i]>ans){
            ans = H[i];
            prev = L[i];
            temp = H[i];
        }
        else if(H[i] == ans && L[i]<prev)
            prev = L[i];
    }
```

This doesn't work on many test cases! Any better solution?

Comment: did you apply "pencil and paper" solution?

Comment: Ya tried for few test cases and wrote solution...but realized it was wrong!

Comment: I guess something is missing. There is no condition which stops us from shopping at all the shops from 1 to N.

Comment: Do you know the potential bounds of what `L` could contain? or is that not available?

Comment: I ask because if `L` only has distinct, limited values (like only having either `1, 2, 3, or 4`) then you can use a lookup and reduce complexity to `O(N)`

Answer (score 2):

Let F[i] be equal to the maximum happiness obtainable if the last shop visited is i.

You can compute F[i] from previous values F[j] by computing the maximum over all valid predecessors (those with j < i and L[j] <= L[i]).

Then the best you can do is the largest value in F[i].

Comment: This is a O(n^2) algo...can this be done in linear time?

Comment: Don't see a way to do better than O(n^2) on this

Comment: But the problem constraints(N<=10^5) requires a linear solution!

Comment: It should be possible to implement this in `O(n log n)`. We need to find the max in `[0, L[i]]`, which we can do in logarithmic time with segment trees for example. If `L` is small it's feasible, if not, there might be a way to normalize `L` into `[0, n]`.

Comment: @IVlad I agree, we can sort the L[i] values in O(nlogn) time to normalize them so your approach should always work fine.

Answer (score 0):

L[i] will determine the possible paths you can take so I think you should be able to build multiple trees with different starting points from L[i] with each node containing H[i] as value.
Then you do a traversal of this tree and the sum in each leave gives you the possible happiness.

Comment: building the trees sounds complex and would be at least O(n^2) by itself to determine the possible children

Comment: Upon further solving, the tree construction was indeed more complex than I imagined.
And my improvements in the construction seem to make it converge to Peter de Rivaz' answer.